# Snap grid on WPF Window Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, I can click the button "Show snap grid" on the bottom left of the designer window. **How to customize that snap grid?** I follow

TOOLS -> Options... -> Windows Forms Designer -> General -> GridSize (8;8)

But (as expected), it cannot change the grid on WPF Window Designer...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it only in Microsoft Blend (or Expression Blend).

TOOLS -> Options -> XAML Designer -> Artboard -> Gridline spacing

Comment: BTW this works in VSBlend 2015 too. But no XAML Designer for VS2015, still. Mikerosoft plz fix